# Merge sheets into one sheet with specific sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro that merges sheets of different worksheets into one excel file.  It works 100%.
I am asking if someone can give a help to improve this macro.
What I need is that **each sheet gets the filename, not a random name.**

Unfortunately, I can not give credits to this code, because I do not know the author's name.

#### The code

```vb
Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    
    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
    
    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count      
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWorkSheet
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a new variable fort he copied sheet:

```
   Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
```

Then you have to adapt the part where you copy:

```
For Each tempWorkSheet In SourceWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set NewSheet = tempWorkSheet.Copy(After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    NewSheet.Name = SourceWorkbook.Name
Next tempWorkSheet
```

With this very simple adaption all sheets will get the name of the SourceIile (Including ".Xls") but it may crash, if you have more than one sheet in a SourceFile.
If you use

```
    NewSheet.Name = SourceWorkbook.Name + "_" + tempWorkSheet.Name
```

instead, you may face some problems, if the entire string exceeds the length of 31 characters.

Comment: Do not work.  It crash

Comment: Where does it crashes? Which Error message?